# how to import and use packages of different versions in golang?

Tags: go, package

I have a project that need use packages of defferent versions.

```
import (
"io/ioutil"
"log"
"os"
"sync"
"time"

versiona "github.com/xxx/xxx/A"
versionb "github.com/xxx/xxx/B"
versionc "github.com/xxx/xxx/C"
)

func Test(version string){
    switch version{
    case "A":
        varTest:=versiona.NewTypeX()
        varTest.Init("init")
        versiona.Do(varTest)
    case "B":
        varTest:=versionb.NewTypeX()
        varTest.Init("init")
        versionb.Do(varTest)
    case "C":
        varTest:=versionc.NewTypeX()
        varTest.Init("init")
        versionc.Do(varTest)
    }
}
```

Package A,B and C have some same functions and few defferent functions, and I only use the same functions but in many places,so I have to write many `switch` expression to do that.

Package A,B and C are clients of a net service. the net service has many versions , so client of it also has many versions such as A,B and C.

I want to build a package that can support all versions.

I tried using driver like sql in golang,but package A,B and C are huge and have many functions and types,and I have to defines many pointers of functions and interfaces of type,so this way is too complex.

Is there a easier way?

Comment: Why do you need more than one version for the same thing? is the latest version compatible with the older versions? if yes you can use only the latest version

Comment: Did you consider to use go modules?

Comment: @Siraf because I can't determine what verison user needs.  The service's server-side is closed source, but it provides a cgo module with a closed source dynamical library to build client-side application. The version of client-side must be same with the version of server-side. My application is a client-side of that service. Users use my application to connect their server-side , but thier servers may run server-side of defferent versions. The server-side provides an API to get its version,so I need choose  pacakges according to the version of server-side.